# reset a count in ruby when putting to screen from parallel arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

This is home work so I would prefer not to put up my code. I have 2 parallel arrays, 1.names 2. ages. The idea is to puts all ages less than 21. I can do this. The problem is that when I puts "#{count}. #{names[count]}, #{ages[count]}" <---The beginning count prints out the index number or position of element in array. Obviously what I want is for it to start at 1. if there are three names...

1. name, age
2. name, age
3. name, age

NOT

5, name, age

6, name, age

I am using a while loop with an if statement. I don't need code, just would like some feedback to trigger more ideas. Thanks for your time, much appreciated.

```
names[name1, name2, name3]
ages[age1, age2, age3]

#view all younger than 21
    count = 0
    while count < names.length
      if ages[count] < 21
        puts "#{count}. #{names[count]}, #{ages[count]}" #works
      end
      count += 1
    end
    pause
```

Comment: Give the example array and your code also to help you out..

Comment: puts is automatically give an new line after printing. What's your code? It because it's your home work? or because you haven't try any?

Comment: No problems doing the work, don't want cheating

Comment: The simplest thing I can think of is to have a second counter variable that only increments inside your conditional.

Comment: OH MY!...lol. The simplest thing ever and for the life of me... Thanks some guy. Totally worked. Duh!

Comment: Just a couple of points.  Firstly, when you have `#{...}` within a string, whatever is between `{` and `}` is evaluated to form the string.  That could be a number (literal), like 4, the value of a variable (like `count`), or the value returned by a method.  One such method is `+`, for example, `count+1`.  I'll put the second suggestion in a separate comment.

Comment: Secondly, when you have to do something with the 'ith' element of each of two arrays of equal length, it is often convenient to first combine the arrays so the two elements are paired up.  If, for example, `a = [1,2,3]` and `b = [21,32,16]`, you could write `c = a.zip(b) #=> [[1,21], [2,32], [3,16]]`.  Now you can iterate over `c` to do what you need to do, such as `c.each {|a,b| puts #{a+b}}"`, which would print 22, 34 and 19 (one per line).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have "parallel arrays" in the first place! Data that belongs together should be manipulated together, not separately.

Instead of something like

```
names = %w[john bob alice liz]
ages  =   [16,  22, 18,   23 ]
```

You could, for example, have a map (called `Hash` in Ruby):

```
people = { 'john' => 16, 'bob' => 22, 'alice' => 18, 'liz' => 23 }
```

Then you would have something like:

```
puts people.select {|_name, age| age > 21 }.map.
  with_index(1) {|(name, age), i| "#{i}. #{name}, #{age}" }
# 1. bob, 22
# 2. liz, 23
```

If you have no control over the creation of those parallel arrays, then it is still better to convert them to a sensible data structure *first*, and avoid the pain of having to juggle them in your algorithm:

```
people = Hash[names.zip(ages)]
```

Even better yet: you should have `Person` objects. After all, Ruby is object-oriented, not array-oriented or hash-oriented:

```
class Person < Struct.new(:name, :age)
  def to_s
    "#{name}, #{age}"
  end

  def adult?
    age > 21
  end
end

people = [
  Person.new('john',  16), 
  Person.new('bob',   22), 
  Person.new('alice', 18), 
  Person.new('liz',   23)]

puts people.select(&:adult?).map.with_index(1) {|p, i| "#{i}. #{p}" }
```

Again, if you don't have control of the creation of those two parallel arrays, you can still convert them *first*:

```
people = names.zip(ages).map {|name, age| Person.new(name, age) }
```